# Return Map with same key and different value separately?

Tags: java

Hello I have a MultiMap of form MultiMap model = new MultiValueMap() in which single key have multiple values. When I return the value it returns in the form

```
a   [x, z]  
b   [y] 
c   [W] -309754843
d   [m, n]
```

But I want to return it in the form

```
a x
a z
b y
c w
d m
d n
```

Comment: do it yourself in a for loop instead of using toString method

Comment: So, iterate on all the entries, and for each entry, iterate on all the values. Which API is this MultiMap from? Where is the javadoc?

Comment: What is the exact problem you encountered when trying to do this?

Comment: Actually I am trying to send the mail. The map data is send to mail. The map data will be redirected to html pages that will take individual value based on key. Now when key a is retrieved in html pages both values will be printed at once. But I want to print each value in different line

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
for (K key: model.keySet()) {
   ArrayList<V> values = model.getValuesForKey(key);
   for (V value: values) 
       System.out.println(key + " " + value);
   }
}
```